# Maven Surefire parallel='both' working the same way as 'methods'

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

I have three test classes: FirstTest, SecondTest and ThirdTest. This is how FirstTest class looks like:

```
public class FirstTest {

  @Test
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(this.getClass() + " " + new Date());
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(this.getClass() + " " + new Date());
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
  }

  @Test
  public void test3() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(this.getClass() + " " + new Date());
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
  }

  @Test
  public void test4() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(this.getClass() + " " + new Date());
    Thread.sleep(15_000);
  }

}
```

SecondTest class is identical (10s+10s+10s+15s = 45s total), and ThirdTest contains 10s+10s+10s test methods.

I'm using Maven Surefire plugin with following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>${excludeTestPath}</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <parallel>both</parallel>
      <threadCount>20</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm having problem with understanding how parallel attribute works. I've tried setting "both", "methods" and "classes" values, but got some confusing output. Please, have a look and explain it to me:

### parallel='classes'

```
Concurrency config is parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, 
threadCount=20, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running experiment.ThirdTest
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:38 CEST 2013
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:48 CEST 2013
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:58 CEST 2013
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.024 sec
Running experiment.SecondTest
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:38 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:48 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:58 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:01:08 CEST 2013
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.054 sec
Running experiment.FirstTest
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:38 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:48 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:00:58 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:01:08 CEST 2013
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.074 sec

Results :
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] Total time: 52.319s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 10 12:01:48 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/354M
```

This is expected result, three classes were executed parallel, all starting at 12:00:38. Build should take 10s+10s+10s+15s, so about 45s.

### parallel='methods'

```
Concurrency config is parallel='methods', perCoreThreadCount=true,
threadCount=20, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running experiment.FirstTest
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:23 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:23 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:23 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:23 CEST 2013
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.142 sec
Running experiment.SecondTest
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:38 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:38 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:38 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:38 CEST 2013
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.037 sec
Running experiment.ThirdTest
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:53 CEST 2013
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:53 CEST 2013
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:10:53 CEST 2013
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.009 sec

Results :
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] Total time: 47.405s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 10 12:11:04 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/354M
```

This is expected result, all methods were executed parallel within single class. Build should take 15s+15s+10s, so about 45s.

### parallel='both'

```
Concurrency config is parallel='both', perCoreThreadCount=true, 
threadCount=20, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running experiment.FirstTest
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:40 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:40 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:40 CEST 2013
class experiment.FirstTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:40 CEST 2013
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.18 sec
Running experiment.SecondTest
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:55 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:55 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:55 CEST 2013
class experiment.SecondTest Mon Jun 10 12:18:55 CEST 2013
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.031 sec
Running experiment.ThirdTest
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:19:10 CEST 2013
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:19:10 CEST 2013
class experiment.ThirdTest Mon Jun 10 12:19:10 CEST 2013
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.025 sec

Results :
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] Total time: 47.521s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 10 12:19:20 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/354M
```

Now, this one is confusing for me. The build took about 45s, while it should take about 15s (longest test method). Why didn't all three classes start executing at 12:18:40? Doesn't parallel='both' mean that both classes and methods are executed at the same time?

EDIT:
I've found [blogpost](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/07/06/running-junit-tests-parallel-maven) that mentions the issue.

Comment: Just try out a new version of surefire (2.15?) instead of 2.9.

Comment: @khmarbaise Tried with surefire 2.14.1, didn't change the situation.

Comment: You are aware of that [`parallel`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#parallel) is an option for TestNG and *not* for JUnit ?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, I'm not aware of that. _From JUnit 4.7 and onwards you can run your tests in parallel. To do this, you must set the parallel parameter, and may change the threadCount or useUnlimitedThreads attribute._ That's from [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-814?focusedCommentId=14455257&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14455257) from [SUREFIRE-814](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-814) (from Jan. 2012):

> "both" is largely untested for a long time and I have no reason to disbelieve that you're seeing this issue.

It's a safe bet that parallel=both has not received much attention in the interim. I verified that the issue affects Surefire 2.15 and I plan to comment as such and vote on the ticket (as soon as I get my signup confirmation). I recommend more people vote on the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in 2.16.
Similar issues should work properly as well
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-797